# Best Key-Value database for tens of millions of records

Tags: couchdb

I'm currently using CouchDb to store tens of millions of documents of variable fields, of variable types.

Unfortunately, creating permanent views for these documents takes an inordinate amount of time and is becoming quite an inconvenience.

Are there other key/value databases out there whereby I can test ad-hoc queries easily and have milli-seconds performance when querying tens of millions of records ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Because Key-Value databases does generally not support ad-hoc queries, due to their architecture (same architecture that makes lookup by key very efficient).

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), which represents a very good compromise between the rigid, structured nature of relational databases and the more free-form approach of a key-value store.